# Does Visual Studio Code support Environment Variables for the ChatGPT extension?

Tags: security, visual-studio-code, openai-api, gpt-3

I would like to open the editor and be able to use the ChatGPT extension without needing to log in via browser or store the OpenAI api key in a workspace file. Ideally, I would be able to use the environment variable stored in `.zshenv`.

I know that Visual Studio Code allows for some environment variables to be set but not all via `${ENV_EXAMPLE}` but this has not worked for me in the `settings.json` file:

```json
{
  "chatgpt.response.showNotification": true,
  "chatgpt.gpt3.maxTokens": 2048,
  "chatgpt.gpt3.apiKey": "${OPEN_AI_API_KEY}",
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can store API keys for the ChatGPT extension.

Per the ChatGPT extension documentation here are the steps:

1. Click Login in your extension.
2. Once asked provide your API key to the extension.

Ref: marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=gencay.vscode-chatgpt

Comment: Hi @Kane Hooper thanks for the comment. Your suggestion adds the api key to the settings file which I check into version control. What I'm trying to do is have the extension read my environment variables which is not being checked into version control.